# Drupal uploading folder directory so people can navigate it in the browser

Tags: file, drupal, navigation, directory

Is it possible to upload folder directory so people can navigate it in the browser?

Comment: Maybe the [IMCE](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce) module is what you're looking for?

Comment: I was already advised to use IMCE but I am not sure how to upload whole folder rather then individual files to the page. imce_filefield is not allowing me to do that.